# How to react differently to many inputs: array, else if, switch, etc?

Tags: javascript

```
var location = prompt("Please enter your name");
if (location == "New York") { 
    document.write ("I love that city"); 
} else if (location == "Montana") { 
    document.write ("Go Skiing"); 
} else if (location == "Texas") {
    document.write ("Rodeo Time");
} else { 
    document.write ("Where?"); 
}
```

So basically I want to do this for 100+ cities with some more information for each city, like the weather, bands playing, etc.

I think arrays would be easier, but don't really know where to start. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: A client-side solution in exclusively JavaScript isn't the best way to approach this. You should have a server side solution that responds to queries with the requested information.

Comment: So have all of my information to display for each State written out and then use retrieve when that state is typed in?

Comment: For example, a restful server that response to GET at `http://example.com/Texas` with `{ "response": "Rodeo Time", "capital": "Austin" }` , generated from a server-side database like mongo or mysql

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would make an object called responses, where the keys would be the cities and the values would be the responses for the city. Like this:

```
var responses = {
   Montana: "Go skiing",
   Texas: "Rodeo Time"
}
```

Then when you get a response, just match it to the object.

```
var Location = prompt("Which state do you live in?");
document.write(responses[Location] || "where?");
```

This should be a cleaner way to organize it. Also, make sure the Location variable is capitalized to avoid changing the window's location.

Comment: tfw our answers are practically the same. One thing I noticed though, using `location` changes your webpage location

Comment: Thanks, this is incredibly simple!

Comment: I would start with a deeper object graph to account for expansion, eg. `locationData = { Montana: { defaultResponse: "Go skiing" }, .. }` ..

Comment: @Isaac Ah yes, you're right. I forgot about window.location. I like how we both took the same route on such an open-ended question

Comment: @JustinHathaway at least our answers even, unlike A Boss

Comment: Right? Lol... @user2864740 Why do you think there should be another level to the object? I don't think he would want more than the response string in the object would he?

Comment: @JustinHathaway He might not now but I find it prudent to build in flexibility when it does not add too much complexity; another level does not. (This is the same reason why I follow the module pattern; even if it's not "needed", eg. A little bit of up-front flexibility can go a long way to mitigate breaking changes.)

Answer (score 3):

I would use an object containing a list of cities that maps to a list of functions to execute

```js
var responses = {
  "New York":function(){
    document.write ("I love that city"); 
  },
  "Montana":function(){ 
    document.write ("Go Skiing"); 
  },
  "Texas":function(){
    document.write ("Rodeo Time");
  },
  "undefined":function(){
    document.write ("Where?"); 
  }
};
var Location = prompt("Please enter your name");
if(Location in responses)responses[Location]();
else responses.undefined()
```